# MYSQL: Counting a casted column

Tags: mysql

I have an table called TableA which has a column called date_entered which is of datetime type. I need to count the number of TableA rows that have been added on a given date.

To accomplish this I must CAST the datetime to a date and COUNT the number of rows that match the given date but i'm unsure how to write this query.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select count(*)
from tableA
where date(date_entered) = '2012-11-15'
```

to count all rows for that date even if the records contain `NULL` values.

Or use `count(specific_column)` to count rows that don't contain `NULL` values for that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(date_entered) AS date_entered
FROM TableA
GROUP BY date_entered
```

And change it to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(date_entered) AS date_entered
FROM TableA
WHERE date(date_entered) = <whatever you want>
GROUP BY date_entered
```

For a specific day.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tableName GROUP BY datefield
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS same_date 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY datefield 
HAVING count(*) >1 ;
```